# Design a class that has 4 private datas and that has a method that returns the largest among the private data

Tags: java

```
public class Quadruple {
private int a1, a2, a3, a4;

public Quadruple(){
    int a1, a2, a3, a4=0;
    }

public Quadruple(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4){
    this.a1=a1;
    this.a2=a2;
    this.a3=a3;
    this.a4=a4;
}
```

I am stuck on how to return the maximum value of the private data. I am not very good at programming and am trying to learn.

Comment: Well, think about how you'd do it on paper. Imagine someone gave you a piece of paper with 4 numbers on, and you were *only* allowed to compare two at a time - how would you find the maximum? (There are various approaches to this, by the way.)

Comment: You would have to loop through them. Using a for loop?

Comment: Sure, a `for` loop would work. Now what would you do inside that loop?

Comment: (hint) if you stored your integers in a `int[]` array instead of 4 separate variables, that might make your loop idea easier to implement

Comment: If I were you, I would return the maximum of the maximum of the first two numbers and the maximum of the second two numbers.

Comment: If I used an array would I have to put it in 
public Quadruple (int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4){
int a []= {a1, a2, a3, a4}
}

Answer (score 0):

I wont write the code for you but here is my explanation. You need a method such as getLargest, and you need to compare each value with each other to find the largest.

---

So lets say a1 = 1000, a2 = 100, a3 = 1 a4 = 10000. You need to set some temporary variable to the value of a1(because its the first value). So lets say we have a1 and automatically set this to b.
b is now set to 1000 and we must compare this to the remainder of the values, so if a2 > b then b = a2, rinse and repeat for the remainder of variables. At the end return b.

The best advice I could give for this algorithm is to simply to write down some values and figure out how you would find the greatest value. You will learn a lot more this way, and find it helps you figure out future problems much faster. Visualizing it helps a lot. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand it mostly. I have a hard time visualizing  how things should be.

Comment: Another option is to use the API, Math.max(int, int) will do the trick. Compare a1 and a 2 return the value to b, compare a3 and a4 return the value to c, compare b and c and you have the max.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int, int)

Answer (score 0):

You should to create the next methods.

```
public int getLargest() {
    return getLargest(a1,a2,a3,a4);
}

private int getLargest(int... as) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int an: as) if (an > a) a = an;
    return a;
}
```